# HttpInterceptor is not working in lazy module

Tags: angular, angular7

I have created the the `HttpInterceptor` which works fine for the App module however it is not being called for featured modules which are lazy modules. I am wondering why it is not working.

1. I have provided the `HttpInterceptor` in `app.module.ts`.
2. I am using the Angular 7
3. `HttpClient` is being used not the `Http`.

Please let me know if you need other details.

#### AppModule

```
    @NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule,

        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        ThemeModule.forRoot(),
        CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
        AuthGuard,
        {
            provide: NbRoleProvider,
            useClass: RoleProvider,
        },
        ZtLoaderService
    ],
   })
    export class AppModule {
  }
```

#### CoreModule

```
export class CoreModule {
    constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
        throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
    }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return <ModuleWithProviders> {
            ngModule: CoreModule,
            providers: [
                ...NB_CORE_PROVIDERS,
                httpInterceptorProviders
            ],
        };
    }
}
```

#### httpInterceptorProviders

```
export const httpInterceptorProviders = [

    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true}

];
```

#### AuthInterceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // do not intercept request whose urls are filtered by the injected filter
        console.log("intercept.........................");
        this.authService.isAuthenticatedOrRefresh().subscribe(response=>{
            console.log("authenticated ----------->", response);
        })
        return this.authService.isAuthenticatedOrRefresh()
            .pipe(
                switchMap(authenticated => {
                    if (authenticated) {
                        return this.authService.getToken().pipe(
                            switchMap((token: any) => {
                                const JWT = `Bearer ${token.getValue()}`;
                                req = req.clone({
                                    setHeaders: {
                                        Authorization: JWT,
                                    },
                                });
                                return next.handle(req);
                            }),
                        )
                    } else {
                        // Request is sent to server without authentication so that the client code
                        // receives the 401/403 error and can act as desired ('session expired', redirect to login, aso)
                        return next.handle(req);
                    }
                }),
            )

    }

    protected get authService(): NbAuthService {
        return this.injector.get(NbAuthService);
    }

}
```

#### Lazy Module : BPOEntryModule

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ThemeModule,
        BPORoutingModule,
        Ng2SmartTableModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...routedComponents,
        BlListEntry,
        EntryListSearchResultComponent,
        EntryListSearchComponent,
        ModalComponent,
        ResultItemComponent,
        ResultToolbarComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [ModalComponent],

    providers: [BPOEntryService]
})
export class BPOEntryModule {}
```

Comment: please share some code. At least show the outline of the interceptor

Comment: Show us one of the problematic lazy modules.

Comment: Added the details.

Comment: with rxjs 6 this import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';  and .do are wrong https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

Comment: @SunilSingh probably the service you use to send request is not belongs to app.module, your service and interceptor should belong to one module so interceptor can catch it

Comment: Added actual full configuration content. I hope, now it will give you some more hint.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you're using Angular 7, so you should probably be using `pipe()` instead of `do()` in your interceptor.

Note:  create a StackBlitz demo if that is not the problem, and someone will figure it out from there

Answer (score 0):

I would check all the providers and components inside the lazy loaded module to see if they are calling HttpClient. If they are this will be a different instance of HttpClient than the one constructed as part of the AppModule initialisation, and hence wont have the interceptors attached.

There is a couple of solutions I can think of, my preference is B:

A) Re-attach the interceptors in any lazy loaded module, I.E:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ThemeModule,
        BPORoutingModule,
        Ng2SmartTableModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...routedComponents,
        BlListEntry,
        EntryListSearchResultComponent,
        EntryListSearchComponent,
        ModalComponent,
        ResultItemComponent,
        ResultToolbarComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [ModalComponent],

    providers: [
        BPOEntryService,
        httpInterceptorProviders
    ]
})
export class BPOEntryModule {}
```

B) Put all HttpClient dependent services inside CoreModule (or created a new module for http services, and create a forRoot method). How your existing core module is written, it's creating a singleton of the dependent services, using the forRoot command:

```
CoreModule.forRoot(),
```

As they are created as singletons with your AppModule, they should have the HttpInterceptors in AppModule attached to the HttpClient instance. The forRoot() singleton pattern is supported by lazy loaded modules so the services should also be available to any lazy loaded modules.

Some more reading here about singletons https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services